# PHP cannot extends 2 class

Tags: php, class

i try work with the a class of database, and connect it to wipe it I build using extends, but I get an error. Example:

```
class Admin extends Sdba{
    // Var:
    public $login = false;
    public $users;
    public $users_list;
    // Function:

    public function UserLogin($char) {

            if($this->login) {
                print "in";
            }else{
                $this->users = Sdba::table('users'); // creating table object
                $this->users_list = $this->users->get(); 
                print_r($this->user_list);
                print "out";
            }
    }

}
```

and my DB class is:
http://foska.pp.ua/codecanyon/sdba/

my error is: `Fatal error: Call to private Sdba::__construct() from invalid context`

Tanks !!

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to private Sdba::__construct() from invalid context

Comment: `Admin` should not be a child of `Sdba` anyway. Just use autoloading to load `Sdba` instead.

Comment: who ? like `Sdba::table` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are inheriting from `Sdba` class, and when you do that, the actual method: `Sdba::table` can be referenced as `self::table` in your child class.

Therefore, the code for creating table object should use:

```
 $this->users = self::table('users'); // creating table object
```

You can also use `parent::table` to reference your function. But, the benefit of using `self` over `parent` is that you can further modify your `table` method in this child class, if need arises.

Comment: this is not work, my error is: `Fatal error: Call to private Sdba::__construct() from invalid context in Line 8`, and line 8 is: `$_admin = new Admin;`

Answer (score 0):

it should use  `parent::table` because you use table method from extended class

```
$this->users = parent::table('users'); // creating table object
```

Comment: this is not work, my error is: Fatal error: Call to private Sdba::__construct() from invalid context in Line 8, and line 8 is: $_admin = new Admin;